# how to read protocol information from a given socket?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

Given a socket, how to find its protocol (i.e., UDP or TCP)?

The thing I have in mind is using "getsockname()" ==> sockaddr_in.

But "sockaddr_in" seems to have no protocol information, only family.

When a socket is created, protocol is supplied. I just what to know how to retrieve.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `SO_PROTOCOL` and/or `SO_TYPE` socket options with [`getsockopt(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getsockopt.2.html).